# DynamoDB auto scaling with Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

AWS released [auto scaling](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/announcing-amazon-dynamodb-auto-scaling/) for DynamoDB. I would like to know how to create a Table with auto scaling via Cloudformation.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the **ClodFormation auto-scaling policy** for DynamoDB table. Hope it gives you some idea about how to form the policy script.

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
  "Properties" : {
    "PolicyName" : "MyScalingPolicy",
    "PolicyType" : "TargetTrackingScaling",
    "ResourceId" : "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:123456789012:table/books_table",
    "ScalableDimension" : "dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits",
    "ServiceNamespace" : "dynamodb",
    "TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration" : {
    "PredefinedMetricSpecification": {
            "PredefinedMetricType": "DynamoDBWriteCapacityUtilization"
        },
        "ScaleOutCooldown": 60,
        "ScaleInCooldown": 60,
        "TargetValue": 50.0
    }    
  }
}
```

**References:-**

[CloudFormaction auto-scaling policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-applicationautoscaling-scalingpolicy.html)

[AWS CLI command for auto scaling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AutoScaling.CLI.html#AutoScaling.CLI.CreateScalingPolicy)

**AWS CLI Command:-**

```
aws application-autoscaling put-scaling-policy \
    --service-namespace dynamodb \
    --resource-id "table/TestTable" \
    --scalable-dimension "dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits" \
    --policy-name "MyScalingPolicy" \
    --policy-type "TargetTrackingScaling" \
    --target-tracking-scaling-policy-configuration file://scaling-policy.json
```

**scaling-policy.json:-**

```
{
    "PredefinedMetricSpecification": {
        "PredefinedMetricType": "DynamoDBWriteCapacityUtilization"
    },
    "ScaleOutCooldown": 60,
    "ScaleInCooldown": 60,
    "TargetValue": 50.0
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!! I created a ScalingPolicy, ScalingTarget and a Role

Comment: How to add multiple tables (resources) to a scalable target?